# Does web browser has network program inside which knows how to send HTTP GET/POST request?

Tags: http, browser, request

If I enter below URL in a browser such as FF and fires in my workshop, I get JSON data back returns my home address based on my ID and its content is displayed in the browser.

```
http://host:port/get/my/address/id={xyz}
```

If I want to imitate same operation inside of web application written in Java, I have to write specific http get request code in a servlet.

My question is:

Does modern web browser like IE and FF have its own network program written in modern programming language maybe C/C++? that runs inside of the browser that would know how to handle http get/post request?

Comment: Unclear what your asking, a browser contains an implementation of an HTTP Client that handles resource fetching, if it didn't it would be much use ...

Comment: @Alex K.: I am sorry if the question is not clear. I admit it is..I've been reading upon how browser works and paid attention to networking component that handles http request. While reading upon it, just a thought came to me how browser physically translates entered URL destined for rest service provider and fires http request. I believe you answered me by saying "a browser contains an implementation of an HTTP client". Now I need to get deeper on what it means. Thank you!

Comment: This is *really* specific to the browser, e.g https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack